# Как правильно указать правило NGINX?

Tags: php, nginx

Имеется следующее правило:

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+)/c/([0-9]) /index.php?loc=main&index=$1&cat=$2 last;
```

при посещении адреса типа : `/Bobik/c/82`
в текущей странице имеются такие же url-ссылки, но при нажатии на них получается следующее `/Bobik/c/Bobik/c/82`

те дублируется со стороны nginx.conf

Comment: Это надо править не в nginx, а в php

Comment: посмотрите в html коде страницы. Скорее всего у вас есть тэг <base href="/Bobik/c"> и те ссылки, которые ведут на /Bobik/c/Bobik/c/82 в коде выглядят так Bobik/c/82 без начального слэша